# Замена случайных чисел

Tags: php

Есть строки

Пример

```
910786584_w269_h230_40_2.jpg
```

Мне нужно заменить 
**_w269_h230_** на **_w2000_h2000_**

Проблема в том что на каждом изображении разные размеры **_w269_h230_** но всегда одинаковы символы. Как правильно зацепится и заменить цифры

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно поколдовать с `preg_replace` или просто использовать `explode-implode`, как пример։

```
      <?php
            $string = '910786584_w269_h230_40_2.jpg';
            $list = explode( '_', $string );
            $list[ 1 ] = 'w2000';
            $list[ 2 ] = 'h2000';
            $result = implode( '_', $list );
            print_r( $result );
        ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ещё вариант в коллекцию ответов. Можно оптимизировать шаблон, и использовать подмаски:

```
$str = '910786584_w269_h230_40_2.jpg';

$patt = '~_([wh])\d+~';
$repl = '_${1}2000';

echo preg_replace($patt, $repl, $str);
```

Если нужно подставлять значения по отдельности, то можно разделить один шаблон на два *(каждый - под конкретное совпадение)*:

```
$str = '910786584_w269_h230_40_2.jpg';

$patt = ['~_w\d+~', '~_h\d+~'];
$repl = ['_w2000', '_h2000'];

echo preg_replace($patt, $repl, $str);
```

Comment: мне кажется, замена такого `910786584_w269_40_2.jpg`  не входила в планы

Comment: @teran а как вы добились такого поведения? )